# Make a new table row every 2 echoed

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a new table row every time a user is echoed.
Here is what I've tried to zero success.

```
<?
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($admin, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    if($i <= 2){
        $i++;
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['ip']."</td><td>".$row['username']."</td><td>".$row['password']."</td><td><img src='uploads/avatars/".$row['avatar']."' style='width:25px;height:25px;' />";
        }
    else{
echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['ip']."</td><td>".$row['username']."</td><td>".$row['password']."</td><td><img src='uploads/avatars/".$row['avatar']."' style='width:25px;height:25px;' /></td></tr>"
$i=0;
        }

    }
?>
```

Any ideas peeps?

Comment: You need to re-set $i to 0 in your else statement.

Comment: I already have it resetting to zero in the else and it still doesn't work.

Comment: you want the userdata echoed in single rows? i dont really understand what you want

Comment: Oh, so you do. Is there a semi-colon missing on the line of code that precedes that?

Comment: What is it doing now?  Is it printing 3 rows, then adding the new row?  Your "if" statement works with i = {0,1,2}; 3 values, so every 3 rows echoed.

Comment: in a moment I'll add a screen shot of what I have and what I want it to do.

Comment: you mistyped "$i=0;" for "i=0" ;)

Comment: @Erbureth - I think that that should probably be added as an answer.

Comment: @Erbureth I fixed that locally but that isn't the issue.
What I have: http://sharemc.net/have.bmp What I want: http://sharemc.net/want.bmp

Comment: Please, fix it in the question too then, as it is misleading.

Comment: Can you also show resulting HTML code?

Comment: There isn't enough space so I'll link it: http://sharemc.net/result.txt

Comment: @Z61 - then make sure the problem isn't your loop bounds.  It is doing what you would expect if the loop bounds were the issue.  Change it to i < 2.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```php
<?
$i = 0;

echo "<table><tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($admin, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if($i++ % 2 == 0 && $i > 1) {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }

    echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['ip']."</td><td>".$row['username']."</td><td>".$row['password']."</td><td><img src='uploads/avatars/".$row['avatar']."' style='width:25px;height:25px;' /></td>"
}

echo "</tr></table>";
```